# Weird Safari pixelating issue

Tags: macos, safari, imac, bug, high-sierra

The issue started after updating to macOS high Sierra. The problem can't be shown when a screenshot is taken or if the cursor is hovered at those areas. So below is image captured from my phone and the screenshot from iMac.

[image: Image captured from phone]

[image: Screenshot captured from imac]

---

I tried ,uninstalling all safari add-ons but issue still persists.